# Ajax parameters always null

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core

I don't know what happened but one of my Ajax query stops working.
I have 2 Views, in first one user choose colors of buttons

```
function choose()

    {
        var a = document.getElementById("button1").style.backgroundColor.toString();
        var b = document.getElementById("button2").style.backgroundColor.toString();
        var c = document.getElementById("button3").style.backgroundColor.toString();
        var d = document.getElementById("button4").style.backgroundColor.toString();
        if (a && b && c && d != "") {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("SetCode", "Home")',
                type: 'POST',
                data: { a, b, c, d },
                
}).done(function(res) {
     window.location.href = res.newUrl;
}).fail(function(xhr, a, error) {
      console.log(error);
});
```

then in controller the colors are saved in singleton class

```
Kod o1 = Kod.makeObject();
        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult SetCode(string a, string b, string c, string d)
        {
         
            o1.FirstColor = a;
            o1.SecondColor = b;
            o1.ThirdColor = c;
            o1.FourthColor = d;

            return Json(new { newUrl = Url.Action("Game", "Home") });
        };
```

after that there is a redirection to method in controller "Game" which return View. In this View next user selects the colors and checks if they are correct

```
  public IActionResult Game()
        {
          return View();
        }
```

```
 function checkcode() {
        var a = document.getElementById("button1").style.backgroundColor.toString();
        var b = document.getElementById("button2").style.backgroundColor.toString();
        var c = document.getElementById("button3").style.backgroundColor.toString();
        var d = document.getElementById("button4").style.backgroundColor.toString();
        if (a && b && c && d != "") {
              $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("Check", "Home")',
                dataType: "text",
                type: 'POST',
                data: {a , b, c, d },
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data == true) {
                        alert("OK")
                    } else { alert("Error") }
                }
            });
```

In controller method I always receive nulls in viarables e,f,g,h.
What's wrong?

```
[HttpPost]
public bool Check(string e, string f, string g, string h)
        {
       
            if (o1.FirstColor == e && o1.SecondColor == f && o1.ThirdColor == g && o1.FourthColor == h)
            {
              return true;
            }
            else { return false; }
        }
```

Comment: Did you miss type: 'POST' in second ajax request?

Comment: Yes, but still the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change `data: {a , b, c, d },`
to `data: { e:a, f:b, g:c, h:d },`.

If you use `data: {a , b, c, d }`,request will pass parameters which name is `a,b,c,d`,so you need to change their name to `e,f,g,h`.

When using `data: {a , b, c, d }`,the request data will be:
[image]

When using `data: { e:a, f:b, g:c, h:d },`,the request data will be:
[image]

**Update:**

You need to change `data == true` to `data == "true"`,When you pass true to ajax,the data will be `"true"`.
[image]

Comment: Wow, I really didn't know that it's working like that, I just thought if I pass 4 parameters with ajax to controller method with 4 parameters so controller will know that a is e etc. Thank you so much. But now I got another problem, function bool Check is returning true value but ajax always returning "else" in success: function (data) {
                    if (data == true) {
                        alert("OK")
                    } else { alert(data) }
                } so I always received alert ("true"). What's wrong?

Comment: I have updated my answer,you need to change `data == true` to `data == "true"`.

Comment: Yes, I just figure it out but I cannot edit my post :) Thanks